# SQL Inequality joins returning cartesian product

Tags: sql, inner-join, cartesian-product, netezza

I have a problem getting join conditions to isolate unique records. My query is returning cartesian products, and I don't know how to make it stop. My tables look like this:

```
Table A         
ID_1    Start   End Name
137 1:00    2:00    Galia
137 2:00    3:00    Est
137 3:00    4:00    Omnia
137 4:00    5:00    Divisa
137 5:00    6:00    Partes
137 6:00    7:00    Tres
137 7:00    8:00    Quarum
137 8:00    9:00    Unam
137 9:00    10:00   Incolunt

Table B     
ID_1Time_1  Time_2
137 3:10    3:57
```

And my query would be:

```
select A.*, B.Time_1, B.Time_2
from Table_A A
inner join
Table_B B
on 
A.ID_1 = B.ID_1 and B.Time_1<=A.End and B.Time_2 >= A.Start
```

And what I get looks like this:

```
ID_1Start   End Name    Time_1  Time_2
137 1:00    2:00    Galia   3:10    3:57
137 2:00    3:00    Est 3:10    3:57
137 3:00    4:00    Omnia   3:10    3:57
137 4:00    5:00    Divisa  3:10    3:57
137 5:00    6:00    Partes  3:10    3:57
137 6:00    7:00    Tres    3:10    3:57
137 7:00    8:00    Quarum  3:10    3:57
137 8:00    9:00    Unam    3:10    3:57
137 9:00    10:00   Incolunt3:10    3:57
```

So it looks like it's giving the cartesian product of the two tables, which makes sense given that all three conditions are met for each record. What I want is for only the record where the times correspond to be returned, like this:

```
ID_1Start   End Name    Time_1  Time_2
137 3:00    4:00    Omnia   3:10    3:57
```

Any advice on how to structure the join to achieve this? I'm working on a Netezza box if that helps with available functionality. Thanks.

Comment: what's the datatype of these times?

Comment: how is `3:57 >= 9:00` correctly true?

Comment: @TomR . . . With the data provided, your query should work correctly (i.e. returning one row).  Are you sure you've included the right query and sample data?

Comment: this is not a cartesian product.

Comment: This is not the actual data, which is proprietary corporate data that I unfortunately can't post. But this data is representative of the problem. And it is a cartesian product in because what the query appears to be doing is testing to see if the inequality joins are met anywhere in the table and then returning ever record where the IDs match, thus giving the cartesian product of IDs and names. It is returning multiple rows regardless of whether the inequalities are in the join or in the where clause.

Comment: dropped my answer which was incorrect because of my confusion between inner and outer join (my mind was still on a previous question, sorry about that), and completed the other one, which is correct.

Comment: I had to try this because I couldn't see anything wrong with it.  I got the desired result as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the following conditions to apply:

```
    A.Start <= B.Time_1 <= B.Time_2 <= A.End
```

Assuming that the column datatypes are coherent (ie. only storing times, not datetimes or timestamps), and the values are coherent (ie. the central predicate in the multirelation above is already valid). These conditions can be rewritten in SQL as

```
B.Time_2 <= A.End AND B.Time_1 >= A.Start
```

and not

```
B.Time_1 <= A.End and B.Time_2 >= A.Start
```

which could correspond to

```
B.Time_1 <= A.Start <= A.End <= B.Time_2
```

Hence:

```
select A.*, B.Time_1, B.Time_2
from Table_A A
inner join
Table_B B
on 
A.ID_1 = B.ID_1 and B.Time_1>=A.Start and B.Time_2 <= A.End
```

Comment: thank you, I hope you don't mind me expanding your answer with some explanations.